# Custom Button on Edit Form

Tags: edit-form, button

I have a small request from my manager.He wants a custom complete button which checks if the fields are empty and if not provides an error and if not then the item gets saved in the list. I know there is a save button already but he does not want the fields to be required through share point column property. I want to implement the above solution but there is a problem : i do not have the admin access of the site so the best i can do is to add a button through content editor and write the validations but i still do not know how to go about it.

If there is anything you guys can help me out with, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if they are empty provides an error and if not the item gets saved in the list*. Please ignore the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  `PreSaveAction()`  function to validate the field(s) before saving the item,

in the new item form, click edit page then add `content editor` web part and add your `PreSaveAction()`, it will execute when user clicks Save button & before the item is saved, below is a sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction() 
{

        if ($("input[title='field name']").val()=="")
            {
               alert('Please, fill the field etc ..."');
              return false;
            }

        else
              return true
}
 </script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Thank You saeed. But how do i create a new button for the java script action to take place.I wan to perform the presavefunction on a new custom button rather than a save button. Save button helps you to save the fields even when all the fields are not filled. So could you help me with the solution ?

Comment: As  i mentioned in my answer, this function will help you validate the fields before saving, above is sample, if you are using jquery like in the sample don't forget to add the jquery js reference to your function @jayantkhushalani

Comment: yes the above code works fine. i have few doubts, could you help me out?

Comment: @jayantkhushalani sure , what's the issue?!

Comment: i am trying to validate the people picker and i am able to do that but how do i set focus on the people picker after i show the error message in the alert?

Comment: @jayantkhushalani this is not related to the main question above, i see you already have another question regarding this, please mark this question as answered and I'll check the other question later today

Comment: Do help me out, it would save a lot of time. Thanks!